# Updating an object fires post_save signal

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have `post_save` signal set up so that every time a new object gets saved the signal is fired.

The problem is this signal is getting fired even when an existing object is updated.
Im updating the object with save() as it says in the django docs but I dont want the signal to get fired when I update.

How do I go around this problem?

I tried to override the `save()` method like `save(force_insert = False, force_update = True)` but it dosent work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't keep the signal from firing, but you can check for `kwargs['created']` inside your [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal handler

Comment: Does the post_save signal emit every time an object is updated?

Comment: @user3030969 from my experiences, yes, but i haven't verified it by looking at the source

Comment: I checked out and the signal does emit every time an object is saved. And you are right, the kwargs['created'] determines if the object was new or old. Thanks man.